# Inputting Foreign Keys in CakePHP Forms

Tags: cakephp

I would like to ask for some advice on how to do something in the 'correct' CakePHP way.

I have a model named `Recipes`, and another model named `Cookbook`. The `Cookbook` is just a list of recipes. There are hundreds of recipes, and I want my Cookbook to contain just 10 of the entries in my recipes table.

Basically, the `Cookbook` only has two columns, the `id` and the foreign key `recipes_id` which references an entry from the Recipes table. Now this is where the problem begins.

Is there a better way to enter foreign keys when adding/editing the entries in my Cookbook model? The only way I can do right now is to use the default  `echo $this->Form->input('recipes_id');`. But since my recipes run in the hundreds, the dropdown menu that CakePHP provides by default might not be the best way to do this especially when the Recipes reach over a thousand.

How do I input foreign keys without resorting to dropdown menus?

Comment: Use a javascript autocomplete, with a remote datasource [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote) is a good place to start.

Comment: The foreign key in the database should be `recipe_id` if you want to stick to conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree - you likely wouldn't want a dropdown.

Here are a few ideas:

- Alphabetical check boxes in grid format
- Search box with ajax/javascript
- Categorized Select boxes - ie first, they choose the type of recipe, then the sub-type, then the actual recipe.